# How can I draw bars and stars faster?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mathcode

I want to use the bars and stars method to list number of non-negative solutions of the equation `x + y + z = 4`. I tried with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
$(0, 0, 4)$ & $\big|\big|\star \star \star\star $ \\ 
\hline 
$(0, 1, 3)$ & $\big|\star\big| \star \star\star $ \\ 
\hline 
$(0, 2, 2)$ & $\big|\star\star \big|  \star\star $ \\ 
\hline 
$(0, 3, 1)$ & $\big|\star\star \star \big|  \star $ \\ 
\hline 
$(0, 4, 0)$ & $\big|\star\star \star  \star\big|  $ \\ 
\hline 
$(1, 0, 3)$ & $\star\big|\big|\star \star  \star  $ \\ 
\hline 
$(1, 1, 2)$ & $\star\big|\star \big|\star   \star  $ \\ 
\hline 
$(1, 2, 1)$ & $\star\big|\star \star\big|   \star  $ \\ 
\hline 
$(1, 3, 0)$ & $\star\big|\star \star   \star \big| $ \\ 
\hline 
$(2, 0, 2)$ & $\star \star\big|\big|\star   \star  $ \\ 
\hline 
$(2, 1, 1)$ & $\star \star\big|\star\big|   \star  $ \\ 
\hline 
$(2, 2, 0)$ & $\star \star\big|\star \star\big|     $ \\ 
\hline 
$(3, 0, 1)$ & $\star \star\star \big|\big| \star    $ \\ 
\hline 
$(3, 1, 0)$ & $\star \star\star \big| \star \big|   $ \\ 
\hline 
$(4, 0, 0)$ & $\star \star\star \star\big|  \big|   $ \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know that, number of non-negative solutions of the solution `x + y + z = 4` is `C_(4+3-1)^4=15`. Is there any way to represent bars and stars faster?

Comment: What do you meen by "faster" ? Faster compilation or shorter code ? And do you want to do this in TikZ (this will probably be not so fast for compilation) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compulsory `expl3` solution: two nested cycles for building the table body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\starsandbars}{m}
 {
  \minthao_starsandbars:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__minthao_table_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \minthao_starsandbars:n #1
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__minthao_table_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { #1 } % ##1 is x
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { #1 - ##1 } % ####1 is y
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__minthao_table_body_tl
       {
        $(\int_to_arabic:n { ##1 },
          \int_to_arabic:n { ####1 },
          \int_to_arabic:n { #1 - ##1 - ####1 })$ &
       }
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__minthao_table_body_tl
       {
        \prg_replicate:nn { ##1 } { $\star$ }
        \exp_not:n { \,\vline\, }
        \prg_replicate:nn { ####1 } { $\star$ }
        \exp_not:n { \,\vline\, }
        \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - ##1 - ####1 } { $\star$ }
       }
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__minthao_table_body_tl { \\ \hline }
     }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \l__minthao_table_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\starsandbars{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An expanded version featuring a key-value interface; the keys are

- `longtable` (boolean); if expressed, a `longtable` is produced
- `preamble`, for specifying the `longtable` preamble with `\endhead` and so on, or anyway something to be set at the start of the table (see the second example)

The picture shows only the first two pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,longtable}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\starsandbars}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { minthao/starsandbars } { #1 }
  \minthao_starsandbars:n { #2 }
  \__minthao_starsandbars_print_table:
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { minthao/starsandbars }
 {
  longtable .bool_set:N = \l__minthao_starsandbars_longtable_bool,
  longtable .default:n = { true },
  longtable .initial:n = { false },
  preamble  .tl_set:N  = \l__minthao_starsandbars_preamble_tl,
  preamble  .initial:n = \hline,
 }

\tl_new:N \l__minthao_table_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \minthao_starsandbars:n #1
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__minthao_table_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { #1 } % ##1 is x
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { #1 - ##1 } % ####1 is y
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__minthao_table_body_tl
       {
        $(\int_to_arabic:n { ##1 },
          \int_to_arabic:n { ####1 },
          \int_to_arabic:n { #1 - ##1 - ####1 })$ &
       }
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__minthao_table_body_tl
       {
        \prg_replicate:nn { ##1 } { $\star$ }
        \exp_not:n { \,\vline\, }
        \prg_replicate:nn { ####1 } { $\star$ }
        \exp_not:n { \,\vline\, }
        \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - ##1 - ####1 } { $\star$ }
       }
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__minthao_table_body_tl { \\ \hline }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__minthao_starsandbars_print_table:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l__minthao_starsandbars_longtable_bool
   { \begin{longtable} }
   { \begin{tabular} }
   {|c|c|}
  \l__minthao_starsandbars_preamble_tl
  \l__minthao_table_body_tl
  \bool_if:NTF \l__minthao_starsandbars_longtable_bool
   { \end{longtable} }
   { \end{tabular} }
 }



\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\starsandbars{3}

\bigskip

\starsandbars[
  preamble=\hline\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$x+y+z=4$}\\\hline
]{4}

\starsandbars[
  longtable,
  preamble={
    \caption{$x+y+z=12$}\\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \caption*{$x+y+z=12$ (continued)}\\
    \hline
    \endhead
  }
]{12}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please help me with `\starsandbars{n}` `n` big. A longtable.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Easily done. `;-)`

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if the requirement is show the numbers in parenthesis *and* do the stars and bars. This `\starsandbars` macro just does the stars and bars:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\starsandbars#1{{\ensuremath{%
  \edef\starlist{#1}%
  \foreach \i [count=\a] in \starlist{%
    \ifnum\a>1\big|\fi%
    \ifnum\i>0\foreach \j in {1,...,\i}{\star}\fi%
  }}}}%
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {{0,1,2},{1,2,1},{0,0,5}, {1,3,0}, {4,3,2,6}}{\leavevmode
\hbox to .75in{(\i)\hfil} \starsandbars{\i} \par
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The question was tagged `tikz-pgf` but if you want to do it with  a `tabular` as in the original formulation this is an ideal job for `\xintFor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{xinttools}
% we need _ as private letter because we will employ \xint_dothis
% and \xint_orthat

\catcode`_ 11
\newcommand\barsandstars [1]{% solving x+y+z=#1 in non-negative integers
  \edef\tmp_N {\numexpr\the\numexpr #1\relax\relax}%
  \def\tmp_a {0}%
  \def\tmp_b {0}%
  \edef\tmp_c {\the\tmp_N }%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
   \hline
   \xintFor ##1 in {\xintegers [0+1]}\do 
   {%  ##1 = insertion location of first bar
       \xintFor ##2 in {\xintegers [{\numexpr##1+1\relax}+1]}\do 
       {%  ##2 = insertion location of second bar
        %     (first bar insertion has shifted by one all things to its right)
           $(\tmp_a,\tmp_b,\tmp_c)$
           &
           $\xintFor ##3 in {\xintegers [0+1]}\do 
            {%  
               \ifnum ##3<##1\xint_dothis{\star}\fi
               \ifnum ##3=##1\xint_dothis{\big|}\fi
               \ifnum ##3<##2\xint_dothis{\star}\fi
               \ifnum ##3=##2\xint_dothis{\big|}\fi
               \xint_orthat {\star}%
               \ifnum ##3>\tmp_N \expandafter\xintBreakFor\fi
            }$
% The trick is to always decide if we need to continue BEFORE inserting \\
% and we must do non-expandable things before the \\
           \xdef\tmp_b {\the\numexpr\tmp_b+1}%
           \xdef\tmp_c {\the\numexpr\tmp_c-1}%
           \ifnum ##2>\tmp_N \expandafter\xintBreakFor\fi
           \\\hline
       }%
       \xdef\tmp_a {\the\numexpr\tmp_a+1\relax }%
       \gdef\tmp_b {0}%
       \xdef\tmp_c {\the\numexpr \tmp_N-\tmp_a\relax}%
       \ifnum ##1=\tmp_N \expandafter\xintBreakFor\fi
       \\\hline
   }%
   \\\hline
  \end{tabular} 
}  
\catcode`_8


\begin{document}
  \barsandstars {7}
\end{document}
```

> [image: bar and stars]

Answer (score 5):

If "faster" meens shorter code working not only for 4, here is a TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
  \def\total{4} % i+j+k = total
  \xdef\y{0}
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\total}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxj}{int(\total-\i)}
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\maxj}{
      \pgfmathparse{int(\y+1)}\xdef\y{\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{int(\total-\i-\j)}
      \foreach \i in {1,...,\total}
        \node at (\i,\y){$\star$};
      \node at (.45+\j+\i,\y) {$\big|$};
      \node at (.55+\i,\y) {$\big|$};
      \node[left] at (-1,\y){(\i,\j,\k)};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

if you set `\def\total{2}` you get:

[image]

And I'll not publish the result for 7 ;)

Comment: coincidentally I prepared my answer with `7` before reading yours...

Comment: @jfbu I've seen this ... this is because I'm a mind reader ;)

Comment: it is funny that as I don't dispose of the convenience of creating nodes at given locations in the context of pure TeX handling of tokens, my first concern was to generate efficiently the bars and stars and that the triplets `(x,y,z)` were thus a king a secondary thing, whereas in your approach it is the exact opposite.